# Keyed Hashing and verification

Tags: hash, password-hashing

Is there any standard algorithm where I can create a hash H(x,k) where x being the data and k being the private key. And verify on other end with H(x,l) where l being the public key?

How it can be achieved?

Comment: Do "Digital Signatures" do what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as SEJPM said you're looking for digital signature algorithms.
If you want names and standards, there's ECDSA based on elliptic curves and DSA based on the RSA philosophy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

Good luck!